# The Stone mapping and the spremum that is preserved by the mapping

Tags: abstract-algebra, logic, boolean-algebra

I have some trouble with proving the following proposition in *Handbook of Boolean Algebra* by Koppelberg.

Let $A$ be a Boolean algebra and $\mathrm{Ult}A$ the set of ultrafilters in $A.$ The Stone mapping $s$ from $A$ to the powerset algebra $\mathcal{P}(\mathrm{Ult}A)$ is defined by $s(x)=\{p \in \mathrm{Ult}A | x \in p\}.$ Let $M$ be a subset of $A$ such that the supremum $\sum M$ exists and $s$ preserve $\sum M.$(i.e., $s(\sum M) = \cup_{x \in M}s(x)$) Then, there exists a finite subset $M_0$ of $M$ such that $\sum M_0 = \sum M.$

I think $M_0$ should be chosen to satisfy $\cup_{x \in M_0}s(x) = \cup_{x \in M}s(x).$ But I am not familiar with a method to take a finite subset from a subset of a Boolean algebra.

Please give me a hint or advice.

Comment: Try to show that if $M_0$ doesn't exist then there is an ultrafilter which contains no element of $M$ and which contains the supremum of $M$.

Comment: (if more details is helpful: if $A'$ is the quotient of $A$ by the ideal $I$ generated by $M$, then the non-existence of $M_0$ implies that $\sum M$ is not in $I$, so the image of $\sum M$ in $A'$ is not $0$, while the image of every element of $M$ in $A'$ is $0$)

Comment: @user8268 Thank you for your comment.  I took a quick look at the definition of ideals just now. Should I consider the ultrafilter generated by $\{ -x | x \in M\}$?

Comment: yes, you can take the filter generated by that and then extend it to a suitable ultrafilter

Comment: My remark was  incorrect. Picking up a finite number of elements in $M$, the sum is not 1 because of our assumption. Thus, the set above has a finite intersection property. there exists an ultrafilter containing the set. Thanks！